# Default BlockDeviceMappings settings for AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling, block-device, aws-ebs

We are using CloudFormation to create an `EC2` machine using `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration`, but we never really specified the `BlockDeviceMapping` to use:

```
Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
Properties: 
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'false'
  ImageId: 'some-image-id'
  InstanceType: 'some-instance-type (e.g. t2.large)' 
  KeyName: String
  SecurityGroups: 'some-security-group'
  IamInstanceProfile: 'some-iam-instance-profile'
  UserData: 'some commands to execute'
```

The [official documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-blockdevicemappings) that the `BlockDeviceMappings` are **not** required, but it does not state what the default value will be when we do not specify one.

What will be the default EBS created when the `BlockDeviceMappings` property is not filled in?

Comment: What is your question about ? If not specified, the default value will be the mapping specified in the AMI used in the launch template.

Comment: Indeed, I just noticed it on [the documentation page for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-blockdevicemappings). If you post your comment as answer, I will approve it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not specified, the default value will be the mapping specified in the AMI used in the launch template, as specified on [the documentation page for `AWS::EC2::Instance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-blockdevicemappings).

Answer (score 0):

The default values of **BlockDeviceMappings** in json format is:

```json
BlockDeviceMappings: [{
  DeviceName: '/dev/sda1',
  Ebs: {
    DeleteOnTermination: true,
    SnapshotId: 'snap-06e838ce2a80337a4',
    VolumeSize: 8,
    VolumeType: 'gp2',
    Encrypted: false,
  },
}
```

Notes:

- SnapshotId change on every instance
- Full json request is here: https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/f3ec44a044293b54af3dbff309fe5c83#file-aws-ec2-snippets-full-request-json